# Weird Error in WinMain() to main() Macro

Tags: c, windows, winapi, macros

```
/** converts 'WinMain' to the traditional 'main' entrypoint **/
#define PRO_MAIN(argc, argv)\
    int __main (int, LPWSTR*, HINSTANCE, int);\
    int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE __hInstance, HINSTANCE __hPrevInstance, \
                       LPSTR __szCmdLine, int __nCmdShow)\
    {\
        int nArgs;\
        LPWSTR* szArgvW = CommandLineToArgvW (GetCommandLineW(), &nArgs);\
        assert (szArgvW != NULL);\
        return __main (nArgs, szArgvW, __hInstance, __nCmdShow);\
    }\
    \
    int __main (int __argc, LPWSTR* __argv, HINSTANCE __hInstance, int __nCmdShow)
```

Now, when I use this code here:

```
PRO_MAIN(argc, argv)
{
  ...
}
```

I get the error:

```
error: conflicting types for '__main'
note: previous declaration of '__main' was here
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What location information was associated with the "note:" line?  Also, did you consider what the note is telling you?

Comment: You also could just not bother with `WinMain` entirely, use `main`, and explicitly tell the linker that you want a `SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` program.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks. Though irrelevant to the question, this pretty much solves all the problems of my project. But won't I run into any problems?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: I'm not aware of any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have broken the rules: [double-underscores are reserved for implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)! (Among other things.)

You simply cannot use `__main`, `main__`, `_Main`, etc. You should pick something else.

I would recommend you make this work:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // main like normal
}

// defines WinMain, eventually makes call to main()
PRO_MAIN;
```

Which has the added advantage that for non-Windows applications, `PRO_MAIN` can simply expand to nothing, and the program still compiles with the standard main function. This is what I do.